# argument of type "struct variable" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c, structure

I know that strcmp is expecting type char I guess and pstate is in this case pointer on structure and I dont know how to dereference this to work honestly.

```
struct  cpu_state
{
    int nextinstructionlinenumber;
    char filename[200];
    char RLO;

    struct instruction instructionlist[30];
    int instructionlistnumber;
    struct variable variablelist[INSTRUCTIONLIST_SIZE];
    int variablelistnumber;
    

};

struct variable {
    //char type[NAME_TYPE_SIZE];
    enum EnumType type;
    char name[NAME_TYPE_SIZE];
    int intvalue;
    char boolvalue;
    float floatvalue;
};    

void AddInstruction(struct cpu_state* pstate, struct instruction* pinstruction){
    if (pstate->instructionlistnumber>=INSTRUCTIONLIST_SIZE){return;}
    pstate->instructionlist[pstate->instructionlistnumber]=*pinstruction;
    pstate->instructionlistnumber++;
}

void parseargument(struct cpu_state *pstate, char name[], struct variable** ppvar){
    if (name[0]>='0' && name[0]<=9) {
        //literal
        //(*ppvar)->type= 
        //(*ppvar)->values=         
    }

    // variable
    for (int i=0;i<pstate->variablelistnumber;i++){
        if (strcmp(name, pstate->variablelist[i])==0){
            *ppvar=&pstate->variablelist[i];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the full code in a minimal example. We have no way of knowing what `pstate->variablelist[i]` is. At least provide the struct definition.

Comment: Ok I edited my post.

Comment: struct variable {
    //char type[NAME_TYPE_SIZE];
    enum EnumType type;
    char name[NAME_TYPE_SIZE];
    int intvalue;
    char boolvalue;
    float floatvalue;
};

Comment: I cant put whole code so i added in coments structure variable

Comment: Looking at the definitions I think you mean `strcmp(name, pstate->variablelist[i].name)==0)`, but I also think you are attempting to program something way above your skill level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes This is really hard task but I am not giving up :D